# Arangodb not started- {config} specified language 'en_US' does not match previously used language

Tags: arangodb

I have tried 3.6, 3.7, 3.8 versions of arangodbs where **3.7 and 3.8** failed to start after installation. Here the output:

```
● arangodb3.service - ArangoDB database server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/arangodb3.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2021-07-28 07:08:45 UTC; 4s ago
  Process: 5273 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/arangod --uid arangodb --gid arangodb --pid-file /var/run/arangodb3/arangod.pid --temp.path /var/tmp/arang
  Process: 5272 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/env chmod 700 /var/lib/arangodb3-apps (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 5271 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/env chown -R arangodb:arangodb /var/lib/arangodb3-apps (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 5270 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/env chmod 700 /var/lib/arangodb3 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 5269 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/env chown -R arangodb:arangodb /var/lib/arangodb3 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 5268 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/env chmod 700 /var/log/arangodb3 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 5259 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/env chown -R arangodb:arangodb /var/log/arangodb3 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 5258 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/install -g arangodb -o arangodb -d /var/run/arangodb3 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 5255 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/install -g arangodb -o arangodb -d /var/tmp/arangodb3 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 5273 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Jul 28 07:08:45 ubuntu systemd[1]: arangodb3.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jul 28 07:08:45 ubuntu systemd[1]: arangodb3.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

I was running it on Oracle VM Virtual box, Ubuntu 18.04 server.I ran 3.6.4-1 in same VM configuration and faced no problem. But 3.7 and 3.8 was unable to start.

Log--

```
2021-07-28T08:00:53Z [16963] FATAL [7ef60] {config} specified language 'en_US' does not match previously used language ''
```

Comment: Can you share the arangod log output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the installer script failed to set the locale

I changed

```
sudo nano /var/lib/arangodb3/LANGUAGE

{"default":""} to {"default":"en_US.UTF-8"}
```

here default is the locale language set to my system
We can check by --  `dpkg-reconfigure locales`